# ¿Se tiene que representar en un diagrama UML las constantes de una interfaz como atributos?

Tags: java, interface, uml

Estoy trabajando con Java en el IDE NetBeans y lo que ocurre es que instale un plugin para generar el diagrama UML, sin embargo tengo una interfaz llamada Peliculable la cual  no me generar sus constantes. ¿Alguien sabe si se toman en cuenta la constantes como atributos en el diagrama UML?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tal vez porque la interfaz no deberia tener constantes, si no que las constantes deberian estar en una clase abstracta??? la interfaz es un contrato de como debe ser tu clase, no deberia tener eso (aunque ahora los lenguajes hayan flexibilizado ese tema)